# Why reading and array of bytes at a time is faster than reading one byte?

Tags: java, byte, inputstream

*"Reading an array of bytes at a time is much faster than reading one byte at a time"*
I saw the sentence [there](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstream.html) while i was trying to learn for input stream. Why this is the case?

Comment: This can get into a reaaallly broad discussion. Basically reading in chunks is just faster than reading a single byte, due to computer architecture, electronics, and who knows what else.

Comment: Which is faster? 1. Pick up a book, read *one letter*, put the book down, repeat. 2. Pick up a book, read a *whole sentence*, put the book down, repeat.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for perfect answers

Comment: It depends on number of connections you make to file to read bytes from. If you read each byte during one connection then it is as fast as reading all bytes in one connection.

Comment: Because I/O is slow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not that obtaining an array of 50 bytes is faster than obtaining 1 byte. It's that over time, it is faster to get 1,000,000,000 bytes of data in chunks of 50 than it is to get 1,000,000,000 bytes one by one.

It's the same reason we don't go to the grocery store for one thing at a time. 
It's the **trip** that takes the most time, not the amount of groceries that we get. 
(groceries being bytes in this example, and trip being the retrieval of data from memory)

Comment: Thank you for your answer with a nice example :)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that this is highly dependent on the kind of input steam. One based on an in-memory byte array is going to be very fast, even for one byte at a time. One based on a file is going to benefit more from chunking. Taking the analogy, it depends on how far away the groceries are. That's why we buy groceries lot at a time, but are okay grabbing just one bottle out of a fridge, even if we might want a second bottle in a few minutes.